# Chrome remote debugging gives broken page when accessed over network

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, mobile-chrome

Tried to expose chrome dev-tools interface over network using

`adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`

and access it over localhost:9222 but it gives an error whereas the default interface is accessible by going to `chrome://inspect`

How to debug android chrome over network. Remote debugging works only if mobile device is directly connected via usb.

Thanks in advance !

[image]